# Filtering a matrix in Power BI but not the rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to filter a matrix of data in Power BI by total for one category but leave the row context unfiltered to allow drill down.

I am using a switch measure but it evaluates down to the row level too and I'm not sure how to adjust it.  Can someone provide a suggestion?

[This image shows filter of >100000 but the filter is applied to rows too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9S5u.jpg)

1. Swtich = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Control Table'[ID]), 1,[Over25000],2,[Over50000],3,[Over100000],[Total Sales])
2. Over100000 = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Net Sales]),filter(Sales,SUM(Sales[Net Sales]) > 100000))

Comment: Also I tried using visual filters but that doesnt help me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify my code to show blank for the top hierarchy, now I just need to filter it out

```
Over100000 = if ( ISINSCOPE(Sales[Cust Category]), (CALCULATE(SUMX(sales,Sales[Net Sales]), filter(Sales, (Sales[Sold To Name] in DISTINCT(Sales[Sold To Name]))))) ,  ( CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Net Sales]),FILTER(Sales, SUM(Sales[Net Sales]) > 100000))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a filter, thanks guys I learned a lot

sumofitem = CALCULATE('_Sales Measures'[Swtich], ALLEXCEPT(Sales,Sales[Item]))

SelectedFilter = IF(ISBLANK('_Sales Measures'[Swtich]) || ISBLANK('_Sales Measures'[sumofitem]),1,0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).